# how to clean sql table base on startdate, enddate and effective date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a really dirty table in which I have a mix between the start date and one values's change effective date.

The table look like this

| id | value | startdate | enddate | effective date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.3 | 2020-10-07 | 2021-02-28 | 2020-07-01 |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-10-07 | 2021-02-28 | 2020-10-07 |
| 2 | 0.46 | 2021-01-01 |  | 2021-01-01 |
| 2 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2020-10-07 | 2021-05-01 |
| 3 | 1 | 2021-08-01 |  | 2021-08-01 |
| 4 | 1 | 2019-03-01 |  | 2019-03-01 |
| 4 | 0.5 | 2019-03-01 |  | 2020-08-01 |
| 4 | 0.7 | 2019-03-01 |  | 2021-05-01 |

When the enddate is empty it means that there is not change planning and when the start date is later and the effective date, it means than they delete an older record and create a new one with other values.

my goal is to clean the table and get it sorted as something like this.

| id | value | startdate_valid | enddate_valid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.3 | 2020-07-01 | 2020-10-07 |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-10-07 | 2021-02-28 |
| 2 | 0.46 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-05-01 |
| 2 | 1 | 2021-05-01 |  |
| 3 | 1 | 2021-08-01 |  |
| 4 | 1 | 2019-03-01 | 2020-08-01 |
| 4 | 0.5 | 2020-08-01 | 2021-05-01 |
| 4 | 0.7 | 2021-05-01 |  |

any idea of how can I achieve this?

EDIT:

I think I was able to get the `startdate_valid` value by using
`MAX([effective date]) OVER(PARTITION  BY id, YEAR([effective date]), MONTH([effective date]) ORDER BY [effective date])`

This make sense as I have the `startdate` included in the `effective date` but I am still stuck in order to get the `enddate_valid`

Comment: You might want to have a read here: <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15>

Comment: thank you so much for your answer I took a look to the documentation you share with me, but I am not able to see how the lag can help as for example, for the `startdate_valid` I need sort the dates between `startdate`  and `effective_date` for a id group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem, I needed to do it in two steps so if someone has a better solution, please share and I will set it as correct

```
SELECT 
    *,
    COALESCE(
        LEAD(sub.StartDate_value) OVER(PARTITION  BY sub.Code ORDER BY sub.StartDate_value), 
        sub.[startdate]) AS [EndDate_value] 
FROM (
             SELECT 
                   id, name,
                    COALESCE(
                        MAX([effective date]) OVER(PARTITION  BY id YEAR([effective date]), MONTH([effective date]) ORDER BY [effective date]),
                        startdate)
                        ) AS StartDate_value
             from table ) sub
```